# About partition tables with Mysql 5.7 in RDS Amazon

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I haven't found anything in the official amazon documentation that tells me at least the pros and cons of partitioning tables in non-IAAS environments.
Has anyone of you had this experience, were there any performance gains?

My my environment
MySQL Community 5.7.33

Comment: You might want to look [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of cons and very few pros of using `PARTITIONing` in any MySQL variant.

The main non-pro is that very few use cases provide any performance benefit (which is what most users naively expect).

More discussion, including the very few use cases with some benefit:
[*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)